# JPA enhancement with Bndtools

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, openjpa, bnd, bndtools

Some JPA implementations use bytecode enhancement to achieve performance. I am interested in OpenJPA and EclipseLink (which calls it weaving instead). They provide an Ant task to do it at build time. Can I make Bndtools run it (unlikely) or give it already enhanced .class files?

One possibility would be to write a Bnd plugin, so I am looking for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [openjpa-maven-plugin](http://openjpa.apache.org/enhancement-with-maven.html), [enabling enhance goal in m2e in the usual way](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered), and moving Maven Project Builder before Bndtools Builder in project properties works.

Answer (score 0):

Using [OpenJPA Eclipse Tooling](http://openjpa.apache.org/openjpaeclipseenhancementbuilder.html) worked for me.

UPDATE: Scratch that, it produces wrong code https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1879.